# EXTJS combobox default value after form layout

Tags: combobox, extjs

My combobox's data is loaded after the form layout.

```
var villeStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: [{name:'idVille'}
                    ,{name: 'ville'}]
        });
var villeInput = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        fieldLabel: 'Ville',
        store: villeStore,
        valueField:'idVille',
        displayField:'ville',
        typeAhead: true,
        mode: 'local',
        triggerAction: 'all',
        emptyText:'Ville',
        width:100,
        id:'villeInput'
    });
```

The problem is that I need to display the last of the store, but even have the valueField, because when I click on a button, this is what I send to server

I did this, but it don't work, it show the last store value, but don't have the valueField

```
villeInput.store.on('load',function(store) {
        villeInput.setValue(store.getAt(villeInput.store.getCount()-1).get('ville'));
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you need to set the value of the combo using the `valueField` (which is **`idVille`**) instead of the `displayField`:

```
villeInput.store.on('load',function(store) {
    villeInput.setValue(store.getAt(villeInput.store.getCount()-1).get('idVille'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    villeInput.store.on("load", function(store) {
                villeInput.setValue(ActualidVille, false);
  }, this);
```

Comment: It don't give me any thing :(